# Using forces to reach a specific velocity

Tags: c++, physics, movement

In my game, I currently move the player by **directly setting its velocity** on key press events. This makes the game feel very responsive and allows the user to quickly change direction.

However, I would like to implement *knockback* and elements like *conveyor belts* that should push the player around. My first idea was to add a `bool underControl;` variable that was set to `false` when the player was under the effect of an external force, but it didn't work well in practice.

Then I thought of another way: how about **adding the exact required force to move/stop the player at a desired velocity** instead of acting on the velocity itself? It would allow the user to move and stop like if velocity itself was being set, but also allow external forces to act on the player.

Basically I want this:

```
if(someKeyPressed()) player.setVelocityX(100); else player.setVelocityX(0);
```

to be expressed like this:

```
if(someKeyPressed()) 
    player.applyForce(getForceRequiredToReach(100, player.getVelocityX());
else
    player.applyForce(getForceRequiredToReach(0, player.getVelocityX());

Vec2f getForceRequiredToReach(float mDesiredVelocity, float mCurrentVelocity)
{
    // What goes in here?
}
```

How can I implement the `getForceRequiredToReach` function?

Comment: Velocity always apply on X ?
If yes, then the force required is the difference between current and desired: mCurrentVelocity - mDesiredVelocity.
However this will do instant stop, so you may want to apply a fraction of this result each frame to smooth the stop

Comment: @Koren: Velocity is both on X and Y. I showed X just as an example.  I'll try using the difference, as I want an instant stop.

Comment: @Koren: it doesn't seem to work - the player accelerates at unexpectedly high velocities

Comment: @Koren: sorry for the triple post: it's the other way around: `mDesiredVelocity - mCurrentVelocity`. It seems to work well! **Post it as an answer, I'll accept it.**

Comment: Glad it worked ! Sorry for the inversion

Comment: Someone mind explaining the downvote? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments,

```
float getForceRequiredToReach(float mDesiredVelocity, float mCurrentVelocity)
{
    return mDesiredVelocity - mCurrentVelocity;
}
```

Comment: This is not returning a force. It is returning a velocity. If you ever starting using proper physics in your games, these things will become an issue. Looking again, I fail to see how this works at all, unless you're getting lucky.

Comment: @Almo: my objects are massless: every frame I add computer force to acceleration, add acceleration to velocity and clear acceleration.

Comment: If your object is massless, then adding a force will not change its velocity or acceleration. F=ma.

Comment: @Almo: sorry, my explanation was poor: I'm not taking mass into account at all. `F=a` in my current design.

Comment: So it's not a force at all. Force has units of kg*m/s^2.

Comment: Acceleration of a massless object in newtonian context have no sense as a=F/m is undetermined. Instead of "massless" this object should be called "object with a mass of one unit".

Comment: Hey, calm down everyone.  It's hardly uncommon to call things a "force" in simple games that just have velocity and acceleration when talking about a change to acceleration.  It might not be accurate to classical physics terminology but it gets the point across.  If it helps, interpret "massless" as "everything is uniformly `m=1`" rather than `m=0`.

Comment: The point of a Stack Exchange site is to ask questions and get answers that are of benefit to future visitors. This one has poorly named variables and functions in both its question and answer. It also recommends a poor solution to a problem, which will probably cause more trouble down the road, especially if this technique is applied in any more complex situations.

Comment: I have to side with Almo. The question is fairly basic, but it has as much to do with physics as with game development, so I think it's important to get the physics right. While I can live with 'speed' and 'velocity' being used interchangeably, this page features so many erroneous terms -- massless is interpreted as m=1 and apparently, force, impulse, acceleration and velocity are all the same thing -- it will spark confusion among visitors with a limited background in physics. It certainly won't help people write anything better than barely serviceable code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recommend using forces to set velocities. Using forces is for altering a player's acceleration, not for setting velocities.

If you know what velocity you want, just set it. If you want something to reach a certain velocity over time, use some kind of interpolation, setting the velocity as you go.

Forces become even more complicated when you remember that the results from forces are dependent upon the mass of the object being acted upon.

Comment: Did you read the question? I think I gave some fair motivations on why I want to use forces instead of velocity.

Comment: I did read the question. I've written a whole lot of player control stuff, having been a gameplay programmer for over a decade. My experience has been that using forces usually causes more problems than it solves, unless what you're really after is in fact changing accelerations, or you're in need of something like realistic car physics.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code from a little platformer I made. Not sure if it will have the effects you want, but it's  way of moving the player using forces. I used Java with Box2D, in case you're wondering. (The code isn't very cleaning as it was for testing mostly, but it works. :P)

```
    if (keys.get(Keys.LEFT)) {
        float desiredVel = -6f;
        float velChange = desiredVel - collidable.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x;
        float impulse = collidable.getBody().getMass() * velChange;       
        collidable.getBody().applyLinearImpulse((new Vector2(impulse, 0f)), collidable.getBody().getWorldCenter());
    }

    if (keys.get(Keys.RIGHT)) {
        float desiredVel = 6f;
        float velChange = desiredVel - collidable.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x;
        float impulse = collidable.getBody().getMass() * velChange;
        collidable.getBody().applyLinearImpulse((new Vector2(impulse, 0f)), collidable.getBody().getWorldCenter());
    }
```

Comment: For the record, you are not using forces. You are using impulses; they are subtly different.

Comment: Like you said, it's not recommended to use forces. :P I tried it and it was somewhat of a not good experience. It should have the same net effect of adding a force to the player so that he reacts with other forces more realisticly unlike when setting the velocity directly.

Comment: Yeah, we were using impulses in a lot of places in Tiny Brains.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vec2f getForceRequiredToReach(float mDesiredVelocity, float mCurrentVelocity)
{
    // What goes in here?
}
```

The function prototype will not allow the function to work as you expect. You are passing two scalars and you are expecting a vector as return value.
Since, as you stated in an comment, your objects are without mass, so you need to treat acceleration rather than force.
Given the current velocity and the desired velocity as scalar you can calculate the required acceleration (also a scalar) to reach the desired velocity within some time (let's call it `t`)

```
float getAccelerationRequiredToReach(float mDesiredVelocity, float mCurrentVelocity, float t)
{
    return (mDesiredVelocity - mCurrentVelocity) / t;
}
```

If you apply this acceleration for the time of `t` on your object it will slow down/ speed up to the desired velocity.